# Выбрать содержимое внутри элемента регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как выбрать регулярным выражением содержимое внутри элемента с вложенными элементами?

> **~{block\s?name\s?=\s?[\"']\s?(.*?)\s?[\"']\s?(.*?)\s?}(.*?){/block\s?}~s**

Регулярное выражение работает, только в том случае если нет вложенных элементов.

Работает без проблем

```
{block name="test"}
   <div>test</div>
{/block}
```

Не работает (обрезает при первом же вхождении {/block}, нужно получить все его содержимое)

```
{block name='test'}
     <div>test</div>

     {block name="test21"}
         <div>test</div>
     {/block}

     {block name="test21" append}
         <div>test append</div>
     {/block}
{/block}
```

Исходя из этого содержимого мы должны получить группу значений таких как:

- имя блока, в данном случае это test
- ключ append или пусто
- содержимое блока

  ```
   <div>test</div>

   {block name="test21"}
       <div>test</div>
   {/block}

   {block name="test21" append}
       <div>test append</div>
   {/block}
  ```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KEQtbB/3)

Comment: Честно говоря, даже с рекурсивным выражением вы мало чего добьётесь. [Пример 1](https://regex101.com/r/oTV8GS/1) и [Пример 2](https://regex101.com/r/oTV8GS/2).

Comment: Первый вариант как раз лучше всего отработал! Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Тогда ладно, раз решение помогло, я добавил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для поиска целых блоков вместе со вложенными блоками можно использовать

```
"~{block\s+name\s*=\s*[\"']\s*(.*?)\s*[\"']\s*(.*?)\s*}((?:(?!{/?block\b).|(?R))*){/block\s*}~s"
```

Это выражение может вызвать `PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR`, если строка слишком длинная.

Вместо `(?!{/?block\b).` используйте развёрнутую версию `[^{]*(?:{(?!/?block\b)[^{]*)*`, вместо `.*?` — `[^\"'{}]*[^\"'{}\s]` (но вторую подмаску с `.*?` надо сделать опциональной, `([^\"'{}]*[^\"'{}\s])?`):

```
"~{block\s+name\s*=\s*[\"']\s*([^\"'{}]*[^\"'{}\s])\s*[\"']\s*([^\"'{}]*[^\"'{}\s])?\s*}((?:[^{]*(?:{(?!/?block\b)[^{]*)*|(?R))*){/block\s*}~"
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/nKjhLl/2).

**Подробности**

- `{block\s+name\s*=\s*[\"']` - `{block`, 1+ более пробельных символов, `name`, `=` между 0 и более 1+ более пробельными символами и `"` или `'`
- `\s*(.*?)\s*` - Захватывающая подмаска №1 между 0 и более 1+ более пробельными символами, которая находит любые 0 и более символов, но как можно меньше
- `[\"']` - `"` или `'`
- `\s*(.*?)\s*` - Захватывающая подмаска №2 между 0 и более 1+ более пробельными символами, которая находит любые 0 и более символов, но как можно меньше
- `}` - `}`
- `((?:(?!{/?block\b).|(?R))*)` - Захватывающая подмаска №3: любой символ, с которого не начинается последовательность `{block` или `{/block`, или же целое регулярное выражение (рекурсивно)
- `{/block\s*}` - `{/block`, 0 и более пробельных символов, `}`

Comment: Только вот проблема возникла. При большом парсинге выдает ошибку PREG_JIT_STACKLIMIT_ERROR

Comment: отличное решение! Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте модификатор жадности U

> ~{block\s?name\s?=\s?[\"']\s?(.?)\s?[\"']\s?(.?)\s?}(.*?){/block\s?}~sU

https://regex101.com/r/KEQtbB/4

Comment: Некоректно... Первая группа должна содержать в себе наименование блока. Вторая группа если указан ключ append, а третья уже содержимое блока. По Вашему примеру выдает ерись полную

Comment: Ну не совсем ересь, выводит весь родительский блок и его содержимое. Теперь вы указали более полное ТЗ. Оказывается нужно наименование и тд.

Comment: Опишите все тз, желательно в самом топике. Какой то еще ключ append, содержимого какого блока и т.д.

Comment: Описание обновил. Это и есть блок 
    {block name='test'}
         <div>test</div>

         {block name="test21"}
             <div>test</div>
         {/block}

         {block name="test21" append}
             <div>test append</div>
         {/block}
    {/block}